# How to return same instance for every class initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, class, instance

I want to create a class that can only have one instance. If I try to make another instance of the class, it will return the first instance.

Comment: it's for practice... from a book

Answer (score 5):

I think you are searching [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) in C++. Here is [implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/singletonrvs.aspx) and here [linux tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Singleton.html) for singleton pattern in C++

Comment: Not a very good implementation. Fails in the face of multiple threads.

Comment: Every time you use the singleton pattern, a kitten dies.

Comment: Every time Jeff Atwood uses the singleton pattern, a Unicorn dies!

Comment: also, the instance is never destructed. that's okay for some uses, unusable for others. i prefer to destruct everything, just to make sure it functions correctly, and has reliable behavior. not destructing can (in some cases) have no considerable impact on behavior - it can actually speed up a program's exit. however, it's generally a bad idea (IMO).

Comment: @David I'm not proficient in c++. I just now this pattern and want to help and try to give reference from good references and updated with linux tutorial. You know struggle with multiple threads in C++ is just a nightmare :)

Comment: @hilal that's fine, I was just adding a point of information that is probably irrelevant since the OP is not likely to be going at this with threads.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Jeff Atwood doesn't use singleton. Singleton uses Jeff Atwood.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is closer to [MonoState](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=147), than Singleton.

MonoState works by having all objects share the same state through static member variables. Whilst the instances are different, the data returned by those is the same. Here is a simple implementation:

```
class MonoStateSession {
private:
  static int _SessionId;

public: 
  void SetSessionId(int newSessionId) {
    //Put threading checks/locks here
    _SessionId = newSessionId;
  }

  int GetSessionId() {
    return _SessionId;
  }
}

//Usage
MonoStateSession session1 = new MonoStateSession();
session1.SetSessionId(123);
MonoStateSession session2 = new MonoStateSession();
assert(session2.GetSessionId() == 123);
```

Answer (score 1):

No... but you can get close to that. For example you can create a class where every instance is just a clone of the same real object... for example:

```
struct TheRealObject
{
    std::string s;

    TheRealObject() { ... }
    void foo(int x) { ... }
    double bar(char y) { ... }

    static TheRealObject& getInstance()
    {
        static TheRealObject trb;
        return trb;
    }
};

struct MyObject
{
    std::string& s;

    MyObject() : s(TheRealObject::getInstance().s) {}

    void foo(int x) { TheRealObject::getInstance().foo(x); }
    double bar(char y) { return TheRealObject::getInstance().bar(y); }
};
```

Note that every `MyObject` instance will still be a distinct object (with its own address for example) but they will just act as a trampoline to the only instance existing of `TheRealObject` both for method and data member access.

Why do you want to do something this strange? May be you're just looking for a singleton instead (like the `TheRealObject` in the above)?